# Saving multiple hilited rows from datagrid in database in livecode

Tags: sqlite, livecode

I have **created a sqlite table in Livecode**

> put "CREATE  TABLE Chapter(ID INTEGER, Units TEXT, UUID INTEGER)" into tSQL
>
> > revExecuteSQL tDatabaseID, tSQL

**Selecting Row from Datagrid code:**

```
put the dgData of group "DataGrid 1" into tData1
put the dgHilitedLines of group "DataGrid 1" into tIndexes
repeat for each item tIndex in tIndexes
put tData1[tIndex]["Unit"]  into theUnit


put "Insert into Chapter(ID,Units,UUID) values('15','"theUnit"','5');" into tSQL


revExecuteSQL tDatabaseID, tSQL
end repeat
```

The Above code is saving only one Hilited row in database.

> > > > But,**My Question** is that I want to **save more than one row** in **Units** column of my table upon multiple hilited rows in datagrid.
> >
> > please suggest if there is any other method to save multiple rows from datagrid in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find a sample stack in the following link that allows you to save multiple hightligted lines of a datagrid to a SQLite database. To create this stack I amended the sample provided in the LiveCode SQLite database lesson-

http://techsupport.on-rev.com/test/Sqlite_Example.livecode

I had to slightly amend your selecting from Row datagrid code as I was receiving an compilation error when copy & pasting it.

Hopefully this will give you some leads.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got your code.but your given datagrid seems to be in table form.while I am using datagrid in form type datagrid.and i am not getting any method for hiliting multiple rows in form type grid.Please suggest.Thanks in advance.

and also for Table type,we cannot select multiple rows in mobile environment.

Comment: Hi Mohammad,

I have update the example so the datagrid is now of form type. I also made some slight adjustments to the databaseInsert handler so that the data is extracted correctly.



               In regards to multiple row selection of mobile, as the datagrid expects the cmd/crtl key to be pressed to make multiple selections this is not directly possible on mobile. It may be possible to programatically select multiple rows via another method but this would have to be manually scripted by yourself.

Comment: The link supplied as a "lesson" does not exist anymore http://techsupport.on-rev.com/test/Sqlite_Example.livecode

Comment: Hi Danny, I have re-created a similar stack and it has been re-uploaded to that directory